# Gulpjs Uglify JS problems

Tags: angularjs, gulp, uglifyjs

```
gulp.task('js', function () {
   return gulp.src(['public/js/**/*.js','public/js/*.js'])
      .pipe(ngmin())
      .pipe(uglify())
      .pipe(concat('app.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/public/js'));
});
```

I'm having an issue with this task and the error is:

```
[13:23:41] Using gulpfile ~/workspace/mean-blog/gulpfile.js
[13:23:41] Starting 'js'...

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: Line 2: Unexpected token function
    at throwError (/home/caio/workspace/mean-blog/node_modules/gulp-ngmin/node_modules/ngmin/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:1156:21)
    at throwUnexpected (/home/caio/workspace/mean-blog/node_modules/gulp-ngmin/node_modules/ngmin/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:1209:13)
```

I think the problem is the paths, but i can not recognize the error.

Comment: I think the `return` is causing the issue - try removing that?

Comment: removed, but it still does not work :(

Comment: return is important for dependencies resolution, dont remove it. Your problem is with ngmin

Comment: Yeah, its on ngmin, after remove it, the exception have changed

Comment: Fixed by removing ngmin and manually naming parameteres like this: `angular.module('myblog').controller('LoginController',['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$location',
`

Answer (score 0):

You should run uglify with mangle option

```
.uglify({mangle: false})
```